# Checking all Invisible buttons rows and columns Android

Tags: android, button

Here is the situation, Im clicking my buttons then make it invisble Onclick. Question is: How can I check  if all of my buttons are invisible(no one left) in columns and rows. Then execute another command.
Here is some of my screenshot buttons that current visible.

[image]

My Code:

```
 private void loadCards(){
            try{
                givingcards.start();

                int size = ROW_COUNT*COL_COUNT;

                Log.i("loadCards()","size=" + size);

                ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

                for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
                    list.add(new Integer(i));
                }


                Random r = new Random();

                for(int i=size-1;i>=0;i--){
                    int t=0;

                    if(i>0){
                        t = r.nextInt(i);
                    }

                    t=list.remove(t).intValue();
                    cards[i%COL_COUNT][i/COL_COUNT]=t%(size/2);

                    Log.i("loadCards()", "card["+(i%COL_COUNT)+
                            "]["+(i/COL_COUNT)+"]=" + cards[i%COL_COUNT][i/COL_COUNT]);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("loadCards()", e+"");
            }

        }

        private TableRow createRow(int y){
             TableRow row = new TableRow(context);
             row.setHorizontalGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

             for (int x = 0; x < COL_COUNT; x++) {
                     row.addView(createImageButton(x,y));
             }
             return row;
        }

        private View createImageButton(int x, int y){
            Button button = new Button(context);
            button.setBackgroundDrawable(backImage);
            button.setId(100*x+y);
            button.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);
            return button;
        }
```

Comment: Assuming you have your `DataModel` which you pass to the adapter, you should have a field in that `DataModel` which tells you if it's `flipped` or not, you can then check if all of them are flipped based on that.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your response. But can you show me an example code with that? btw. I generated that buttons manually in my code.

Comment: I could, if you post your `DataModel` class which you pass to the adapter. Maybe your adapter also and when you switch `visibility` of your view

Comment: What kind of layout it is? it is GridView, RecyclerView or a simple layout - RelativeLayout, LinearLayout?

Comment: Put your code of generating buttons.

Comment: Okay. I'll put it.

Answer (score 1):

there is a simple solution you can apply, that is using a variable as counter, it will update whenever onClick() be called

```
   int counter = 0;

    public void onClick(View view) {
      // visible button ..
      counter++;
      checkButtonsStatus();
    }

    public checkButtonsStatus() {
    if (counter == (4*4)) {
      // all buttons is visible
    }
    }
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: Wow, thanks buddy. I'll try this later.

Comment: you're welcome, please comment if you have any issue with this solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

Add method below in `createImageButton();` :

```
button.setTag(100*x+y);
```

in your `buttonListener` put add following code :

```
public void checkCards(){
                if(cards[secondCard.x][secondCard.y] == cards[firstCard.x][firstCard.y]){
                    successpair.start();
                    firstCard.button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    secondCard.button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                else {
                    wrongpair.start();
                    secondCard.button.setBackgroundDrawable(backImage);
                    firstCard.button.setBackgroundDrawable(backImage);
                }

                firstCard=null;
                secondCard=null;


                // check here


                boolean isAnyViewVisible = false;

                for (int y = 0; y < ROW_COUNT; y++) {
                    for (int x = 0; x < COL_COUNT; x++) {
                        View view = findViewWithTag(100 * x + y);

                        if (view!=null && view.getVisibility() == VISIBLE) {
                            isAnyViewVisible = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (isAnyViewVisible) {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!isAnyViewVisible) {
                    // write your code here, which you want to execute when all views are invisible

                }


            }
```

Change this method too to this one :

```
    // check here
    private void turnCard(Button button,int x, int y) {
        button.setBackgroundDrawable(images.get(cards[x][y]));

        if(firstCard==null){
            firstCard = new Card(button,x,y);
```

//setTag here
                firstCard.button.setTag(100*x+y);
            }
            else{

```
            if(firstCard.x == x && firstCard.y == y){
                return; //the user pressed the same card
            }

            secondCard = new Card(button,x,y);
```

//setTag here

```
            secondCard.button.setTag(100*x+y);

            turns++;
            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1)).setText("Tries: "+turns);


            TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try{
                        synchronized (lock) {
                            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("E1", e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            };

            Timer t = new Timer(false);
            t.schedule(tt, 1300);
        }


    }
```

Comment: I tried your code but my app got crash and stop.

Comment: what crash is it?

Comment: I have changed code, try this one

Comment: btw. I had already Onclick listener with this execution, where I can put your code in order to work? Just check.

Comment: below turnCard(); at last line

Comment: put the code written below // put this at end of method

Comment: this code is written in fragment or Activity?

Comment: Written in MainActivity Sir.

Comment: I had error in getview:  The method getView() is undefined for the type MainActivity.ButtonListener

Comment: Here is my full source code of MainActivity.java: http://pasted.co/91d42384 maybe you could check it.

Comment: I edited code using your code, change onCLick method like this

Comment: Im having error duplicate variable x and y

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173363/discussion-between-kenth-joshua-espina-and-nehak).

Comment: Hello, I updated code, you should put that method at last of checkCards()

Comment: Hello Sir, Thank you for reply, Unfortunately after I click two buttons it executes command even though they are not invisible. Maybe I can share to you my full project to see. How can I send it to you?

Comment: just share the main_interface.xml code

Comment: here is my main_interface.xml Sir: https://dropmb.com/download/46bf3bbbb0e7d9551b07837df4306857.html